# Haproxy Block URL with specific character URL ha

Tags: haproxy

We found that one of the our applications have vunerability, vendor of app recommend block all requests that contains `${` in URL. I've tried path_reg for it. But it now working, also tried $%7B, but it not working too. Maybe I need some escape symbols?

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.